# UART, return to the start of the page

Tags: c, microcontroller, uart, 8051

Is it possible,somehow,to return to the beginning of the page, not line, page.
Using something like `"hello\r"` would,obviously, write "hello" and return to the start of the line.

But what about when I am on a second line?
So after `"hello\n"` it would put me on a second line.
Can I somehow return back to the 1st line.

From the research I have conducted it seems that you can only operate on 1 line, but I am not 100% sure and thus would like someone to confirm this.

Programming in C and using RealTerm.

Comment: What about `^L` (i.e., `\f`)?

Comment: No, it just does what it is described to do: new page
I would like to overwrite the 1st line

Comment: Have you tried embedding an ANSI escape sequence such as **Cursor Home** `<ESC>[{ROW};{COLUMN}H` which sets the cursor position where subsequent text will begin. If no row/column parameters are provided (ie. `<ESC>[H`), the cursor will move to the home position, at the upper left of the screen. See http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code is also a good place for ANSI escape codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RealTerm has an ANSI terminal emulation mode.

Find the "Display Formatting " configuration dialog and select the **Ansi** option.

Now you can embed an escape sequence for **Cursor Home** much like you embed the **newline**.

```
<ESC>[H
```

Where, of course, `<ESC>` means the single character `0x1b`. You can implement it like this

```
sprintf(buffer, "%c[Hmy text\n", 27);
transmit(buffer);
```

or similar.

Comment: I am not 100% sure on how to implement this in my program. I tried 
key_string("<ESC>[H"); which, obviously is wrong, but didn't really know what else to do. It all has to be controlled through the program I wrote.

Comment: Improved explanation.

Comment: Do not do `"%c"` with a constant. C has a syntax for that: `strcpy(buffer, "\x1B[Hmy text\n");`.

Comment: It just prints [H into terminal

Comment: Did you enable the Ansi terminal emulation?

Comment: @rodrigo thanks I forgot about `\0x1b` but why should one not use a constant for `%c`? A `char` or an `int` or a constant will all be stacked as an `int`.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Yes, but it is lousy. It is like writing `sprintf(buf, "c:%cwindows", 92)` instead of `strcpy(buf, "c:\\windows")`. It is an unnecesary workaround.

Comment: @WeatherVane nvm, it was my mistake, this work. I must say it is a bit annoying to do this all the times.
Also, is this RealTerm specific thing?

Comment: @WeatherVane is this method RealTerm specific or will it work on other term emulators too

Comment: @s3v3ns ANSI terminal emulation is a standard which many terminals support, please google it for more info.

Comment: *"it is a bit annoying to do this all the times"* then write a function to do it. `int termhome(void) { return(transmit("\x1b[H")); }`